# Read Excel file from memory stream in C# Console application

Tags: c#, excel, azure, console-application

I am fetching an Excel file from ftp and getting that file in a memory stream. I have to read that file from memory stream. I tried through Excel Interop but it is not accepting memory stream as a parameter in

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strm, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, 
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

According to system requirement that I cannot save that file temporary; because I am using Azure web jobs for Console application deployment. Is there any way to read file from memory stream or can I convert that memory stream into an array of string?

Comment: You can't load an Excel file form a `Stream` if you're using the Office interop libraries. In fact, you probably shouldn't be using that library on Azure either. There's other libraries out there that will do this for you though.

Comment: @DavidG Can please suggest me other libraries that will be help full.

Comment: Most of the time you don't need to load file into inetrop. You can use better tools that can work on the background

Answer (score 0):

Also [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com) accepts streams, including MemoryStream.
I don't know if you need only data in cells from Excel, or other information, but the code bellow is only for data:

```
ExcelDocument excelWorkbook = new ExcelDocument();
DataSet ds = excelWorkbook.easy_ReadXLSActiveSheet_AsDataSet(memoryStream);
```

More details about reading Excels, you can find at this location:
https://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/read-excel-file-in-dot-net.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no MS Office present in the  Azure Webjob, so we cannot use Microsoft.Office.Interop Dll in the Azure Webjob. Please have a try to use [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) to do that. The following is the demo code from the [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478410.aspx). I also find another  tutorials about how to [Read and Write Microsoft Excel with Open XML SDK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK).

```
public static void OpenAndAddToSpreadsheetStream(Stream stream)
{
    // Open a SpreadsheetDocument based on a stream.
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument =
        SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true);

    // Add a new worksheet.
    WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
    newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

    Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
    string relationshipId = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart);

    // Get a unique ID for the new worksheet.
    uint sheetId = 1;
    if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
    {
        sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
    }

    // Give the new worksheet a name.
    string sheetName = "Sheet" + sheetId;

    // Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
    sheets.Append(sheet);
    spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

    // Close the document handle.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();

    // Caller must close the stream.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you to use [`ExcelDataReader 3.1.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) to read data from an Excel file.
Now you can use that `MemoryStream` in `ExcelReader` like this:
Note that reader of old Excel files -`.xls`- is different form newer files -`.xlsx`-.

```
var excelReader = originalFileName.EndsWith(".xls")
                ? ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)
                : ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

---

If you want to extract a `string` from your `MemoryStream` you can use a `StreamReader`:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
var stringResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

---

If you want to work over a `FileStream` you can copy your `MemoryStream` to it like this:

```
memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```