# Convert byteArray to xls file

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, office-interop, memorystream

Core 7 application.
From an API call, I am receiving a xls file through Json and need to read/process the file.

I convert the string to a byteArray[]

```cs
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(dta);
```

Then I use a MemoryStream

```cs
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
  // need to convert memStream to file.
}
```

OfficeOpenXml can only convert xlsx files.

[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel) will not convert byteArrays to a file.

I have asked the host company for the data in json format and/or in xlsx.

I'm not sure they will modify the output file/format.

What other options are there?

Comment: Is there any problem with copying to a temp file and using [`Workbooks.Open()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia)?

Comment: If not, maybe see [Read Excel file from memory stream in C# Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45649792) or [C# open and edit .xls file right from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51721284).

Comment: "need to convert memStream to file" is an odd comment, IMO. If you just want to save the data as a file, is there any reason you're not just using `File.WriteAllBytes(path, byteArray)`? The fact that it represents an Excel spreadsheet is irrelevant to how you write the bytes to a file.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I reckon the problem is that [`Workbooks.Open(string Filename, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia) does not have an overload that takes a `Stream` and OP would like to directly read the `.xls` content in the `byte []` array without having to save to disk.  But I could be wrong, and it would be helpful for them to clarify why using a temp file is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

[Spire.XLS](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-excel-for-net-now.html) supports reading Excel files from streams and saving them to files in XLS, XLSX, XLSM, XLSB and many other file formats like PDF, CSV, HTML, XML, ODS and XPS.

```
using Spire.Xls;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace MSToXLS
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
                workbook.LoadFromStream(memStream);

                //do something...

                workbook.SaveToFile("ByteArrayToXls.xls", FileFormat.Version97to2003);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that developed this library.